# Git force a manual merge

Tags: git

I'm working with a git repo that has two branches:

Branch A runs on specially designated hardware

Branch B is based on a specific commit in Branch A, and removes some code to allow it to run on my laptop.

I've made some changes on Branch B that I'd like to merge into Branch A, but whenever I attempt a merge (even with `git merge --no-commit --no-ff`) it will automatically merge the part of Branch B where I removed all of the specific device code for Branch A.

I'd like to be able to force a manual merge, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Merging is the wrong terminology here, and `--no-commit` and `--no-ff` are completely unrelated to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is there a correct terminology?  I'd just like to move some, but not all, changes from one branch to another.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, you're after a "cherry pick".